# Is there any way to get notified if a automation with file drop skipped or never runs

Tags: marketing-cloud

Hi I am looking for a way to get the notification if the file drop automations got skipped or never runs.

I checked a found a script which is kind of pulling the real tine status if the automation with help if the api. I implemented that but that is not meeting the requirements for the file drop automation.

My activity start only when someone drop the file on the FTP so I am looking for a solution to get the notification if someone forgot to drop the file and automation never runs.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try something like this... select Daily or hourly based on ur requirements.
Choose "Scheduled" --> "Import" activity --> Add a "Verification" activity -->Send notification if  record count is < 1

Comment: Thanks, Vishal, I think the best way is to Create a script activity to insert the data in the data extension with Getdate and insert the record. This will be the first step after the automation starts. I will schedule another automation every evening to check if the DE has today's record if yes then means automation runs if no means no automation runs today.

Comment: Wow this process is even better